# Possible bottlenecks when rendering sprites programmatically in Unity using Graphics.DrawMesh()?

Tags: unity, rendering

I'm currently trying to render sprites in Unity without using a sprite renderer component.

So far using Graphics.DrawMesh() I have this:

```
public void Draw(Sprite sprite, Vector3 pos) {
    Material mat = new Material(spriteMaterial) {
        mainTexture = sprite.texture
    };
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh() {
        vertices = Array.ConvertAll(sprite.vertices, x => (Vector3)x),
        triangles = Array.ConvertAll(sprite.triangles, x => (int)x),
        uv = sprite.uv
    };
    Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, Matrix4x4.TRS(pos, Quaternion.identity, sprite.bounds.size), mat, 0);
    }
```

Everything was working fine except after doing a test with a about hundred or so sprites my fps went down to around 30.

So the question is, is this normal? If not, what potential bottlenecks could there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's bacause of this:

```
    Material mat = new Material(spriteMaterial) {
    mainTexture = sprite.texture
};
```

It just creates a new material to each sprite. This means each game object has it's own material, and Unity cannot apply dynamic batching, so it produces 1 draw call for each game object. See if you have lots of draw calls in the statistics panel (in Game window). If you have so many draw calls and 0 "saved by batching" draw calls, maybe this is the problem.

To solve it, instead of creating a new material for each sprite, just create only 1 material, and use it for all of them.